# NUnit CollectionOrderedConstraint throws NullReference exception on a non-null public readonly field

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-3.0

So I have the following code for a unit test using NUnit 3 in C#:

```
var skills = new[]
{
    new Skill("aaaa"), //parameter is Name
    new Skill("kkkk"), //parameter is Name
    new Skill("zzzz"), //parameter is Name
};

Assert.That(skills, Is.All.Not.Null);

var skillNames = skills.Select(s => s.Name);
Assert.That(skillNames, Is.All.Not.Null);
Assert.That(skillNames, Contains.Item("aaaa"));
Assert.That(skillNames, Contains.Item("kkkk"));
Assert.That(skillNames, Contains.Item("zzzz"));

Assert.That(skills, Is.Ordered.By("Name")); //Fails
```

When it gets to the `Ordered` assertion, it fails and throws `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` from `CollectionOrderedConstraint.Matches(IEnumerable actual)`.  Obviously, the values are not null.  This is verified by the following test passing successfully:

```
var skillNames = new[]
{
    new Skill("aaaa").Name,
    new Skill("kkkk").Name,
    new Skill("zzzz").Name,
};

Assert.That(skillNames, Is.Ordered); //Passes
```

I know the issue is not with the `By` constraint, as this test also passes:

```
var characters = new[]
{
    new Character { InterestingTrait = "aaaa" },
    new Character { InterestingTrait = "kkkk" },
    new Character { InterestingTrait = "zzzz" },
};

Assert.That(characters, Is.Ordered.By("InterestingTrait")); //Passes
```

The only difference I know of between the failing case and the passing cases is that in the failing case, the field we are checking is a public `readonly` field.   Why would that throw a null reference exception?  Is there a known issue with this in NUnit?

Comment: Could you provide this in the form of a [mcve] so we can reproduce it for ourselves easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a problem with the member being `readonly`, just the fact that it is a field, not a property. To workaround it, switch your field to a readonly property,

```
public string Name { get; }
```

If you read the [NUnit documentation for CollectionOrderedConstraint](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/CollectionOrderedConstraint), or look at the signature for `By(string propertyName)` you will notice that only properties are mentioned. NUnit should probably handle public fields or give a better error message, so I will enter an issue.

**Update**: I entered the issue https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/2292

Comment: This did indeed fix the problem, changing the values from fields to properties.  Thanks!